# How to put the information of the notification received into a UITableView in the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to implement Apple Push Notification Service on my app. I followed the [Pushbots tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9zw34QbYRx5oq8jZ-wdfHA4ww5K2O_jq) but is it possible to get the information from the notification and put it into a table?

The only code I've added to my project is in the `AppDelegate.m` file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Pushbots sharedInstanceWithAppId:@"--my app id--"];
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // This method will be called everytime you open the app
    // Register the deviceToken on Pushbots
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] registerOnPushbots:deviceToken];
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Notification Registration Error %@", [error userInfo]);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //Handle notification when the user click it while app is running in background or foreground.
    [[Pushbots sharedInstance] receivedPush:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing what you desire to do here, I have posted my answer below. Ping me, if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userInfo` is the dictionary containing push notifications. `aps` is the key for push notifications body.

Save the payload in **NSUserDefaults** and later use it in ViewController to populate the tableView.

```
    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  {
                // you can get the required message as below
                NSString *msg = [userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
                NSLog(@"Push Notification:%@",msg);

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:msg forKey:@"ReceivedNotifications"];
                //This is how you save object in NSUserDefaults
  }
```

Now in your `ViewController.m`

```
{
NSMutableArray *notificationArray= [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
notificationArray= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"ReceivedNotifications"];
}
```

Load your tableView using this `notificationArray`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with NSUserDefaults. How do I call it in the ViewController?

Comment: Where did the "array" come from?

Comment: Sorry for typo, it's actually **notificationArray**.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a notification is  received, didReceiveRemoteNotification will be called with payload(i.e user info) .You can use parse the payload and show it to the table view

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code into your project.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"id"]  forKey:@"pushstring"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue];

NSLog(@"value of array is %@",userInfo);
//NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// [arr addObject:[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"]valueForKey:@"category"]];
NSLog(@"value of array is %d",[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badgecount"] intValue]);
//    for (arr in userInfo) {
//        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", arr, [userInfo objectForKey:arr]);
//    }
//    NSLog(@"value of alert is %@",[arr objectAtIndex:2]);
//  NSLog(@"value of category is %@",[[arr objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:2]);

}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This prints it out at the console. How do I bring the information over to ViewController to put it into a table and display it on the user's screen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when get a notification in didReceiveRemoteNotification method you will get a payload from userinfo so that you can modify your table with the data.